# How to add a row with another row

Tags: sql

How to add a row to another row?

Example:

```
emp_id  salary  updated salary
1         100      300
2         200      500
3         300      700
4         400
```

Here in this example, `emp_id` and `salary` are two columns. I want to add first and second salary and show it in the first row as 300.

How to do it in SQL?

Comment: what code you tried?

Comment: can u specify, which sql you have used so far... bcuz `LEAD` is functional in MSSQL -2008

Comment: @Anto Check my answer and do not forget to accept as correct  answer If It worked for you.

Comment: @Anto, below solution worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) function.

```
SELECT emp_id,
       salary,  
       salary + LEAD(salary) OVER (ORDER BY (salary)) AS [updated salary]
FROM Counting
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with lead function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx

```
SELECT *,Salary + LEAD(Salary, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY emp_id)"updated salary"
FROM Table
```

Comment: Seems you copied my answer, with my previous mistakes.

Comment: It should be `LEAD(Salary)` instead of `LEAD(Salary, 1,0)` and `[updated salary]` instead of `updated_salary`.

Comment: can u please check this link ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx

Comment: If you use `LEAD(Salary, 1,0)` last row in `[updated salary]` column will be `400` instead of `null`. As you see Anto asked to be last row as `null` (empty field)

Comment: K i agree with u @StanislovasKalašnikovas  ... but dont blame others blindly be honest ok